# YouTube API playlistItems.insert issue in contentDetails.startAt and endAd

Tags: youtube-data-api

I can insert items to a playlist using the API but whenever I set a startAt and endAt in the contentDetails, the inserted Item doesn't edit the start and end when playing it in my youtube playlist. Also, in the playlistitemresponse, it doesn't show the contentDetails.startAt and endAt.

```
contentDetails: Object
endAt: "PT2M04S"
note: "asdfs"
startAt: "PT1M29S"
```

here's the object of my contentDetails? I am missing something to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed internally. Feel free to [file a feature request in public tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) and let me know the id to get notified when this is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I filed the defect and here's the id [Issue 5453](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5453)